# Visual Basic Handles and Multiple Variables with same name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've made a program in Visual Basic to open files by clicking in a PictureBox, but as a result, I've ended up with 36 pictureboxes, and it's being a pain to handle every one of them, as the only way I've discovered to reference the PictureBox(Nº)
was making
`Dim pictureBoxes(35) As PictureBox`

and setting each one as following:

```
pictureBoxes(0) = PictureBox1
pictureBoxes(1) = PictureBox2
pictureBoxes(2) = PictureBox3
...
pictureBoxes(35) = PictureBox36
```

Then I could use it in a For Loop:

```
PictureBoxes(i).Image = iconForFile.ToBitmap()
```

So, my question is, is there a way to make it easier to reference, instead of doing that way?
The same thing is kinda making me wonder in the Handles part of the code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox4.Click, PictureBox5.Click, PictureBox6.Click, PictureBox7.Click, PictureBox8.Click, PictureBox9.Click, PictureBox10.Click, PictureBox11.Click, PictureBox12.Click, PictureBox13.Click...
```

Any light would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: You could try to use it all in a loop and set the values the same way, with a loop. Then declare the event handles also within the same loop.

Comment: The Handles keyword is nice for a designer.  In code you use the AddHandler statement.  Which makes it trivial to give all pbs the same event handler, just a For loop.

Comment: @HansPassant , the choice for using each one individually was to see with precision which picturebox has been selected, if a event handler is set by a for loop it would probably give the same result for all pictureboxes set this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your controls are structured on the form, but if they are part of the same collection, a flowpanel for example, you can get all of the controls of a certain type. In your case you want to be able to access individual boxes so you can do this once and store the boxes in the list as you are already doing.

```
Dim pictureBoxes = FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().Tolist()
For Each picture in pictureBoxes
    AddHandler picture.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click
Next
```

Comment: I don't think `ToList` is required here, but it still works.

Comment: This is indeed very helpful, thanks!  Just a simple question, how would I refer to each picturebox added?

Comment: You would still have to refer to them by index, or use `.Find()` if they have suitably unique names like so: `Dim selectedBox = pictureBoxes.Find(Function(p) p.Name = "MyComputerPictureBox")`